# Select2: override 'container' in formatSelection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Select2's formatSelection function provides a `container` that is the DOM element to which the selected choice should be appended.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#documentation

I'm using this as a multiple selection implementation and I'm not able to find a way to override the default container, which is `.select2-search-choice`. I want the user to choose an option and have it appear in a location other than the input field itself.

In looking at Select2's source and the `addSelectedChoice` method, I'm not sure you're actually able to change the container. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. For the record, the project owner (inadequately) addresses this issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/6AB06BK8BkY)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `addSelectChoice` function; I've hacked a bit at the source to accomplish something close enough to what I want, but hardly a sharable solution (yet).

Answer (score 1):

My ad-hoc solution:

Add a similar looking container to your page:

```
 <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" style="width: 200px;">
     <ul class="select2-choices choicesOutput"></ul>
 </div>
```

This will be the container to hold the chosen options.

Then, in the `addSelectedChoice` function, replace the following line:

```
choice.insertBefore( this.searchContainer );
```

with this:

```
choice.appendTo("ul.choicesOutput");
```

Then, if you don't want the output box to be there when nothing has been selected, add this style to your **CSS**:

```
ul:empty
{
    display: none;
}
```

If you want the location to be dynamic, you can trace the call chain and pass a parameter through to replace `ul.choicesOutput`.

Comment: I appreciate your work here and I think it probably works (haven't tested it), but because you have to modify the source I'm not going to accept this as an answer. Hope you understand why. Best of luck to you on your implementation!

Comment: You might want to modify your question such that it indicates that you're only looking for answers which do not require modifying the source.

Comment: I'm also looking for an option that does not modify source.